# MatLab - accessing variables after a function is done with them

Tags: matlab, function, global-variables

I'm new to MatLab and having difficulties using the results of my functions.

My program loads a .mat file as an object, and then for each variable in the .mat, it runs an analysis. The actual analysis is done by a function called in the for loop. The results of the analysis are stored by the function in an array - or they should be! As follows:

```
function main()
    object = matfile('data.mat')
    vars = (fieldnames(object))
    resultarray = zeros(length(vars))
    for index = 1:length(vars)
        var = vars(index)
        x = object.var
        resultarray = analysis(x, index)
    end
end

function resultarray = analysis(x, index)
    %does stuff to x
    resultarray(index) = x
    disp(resultarray(index))
end
```

The problem is - none of my variables are visible! The workspace is empty. The disp() function prints the value I assigned so I know the function is working, but how do I access resultarray after the program has finished? I have tried declaring it as a global at the beginning of main(), which doesn't seem to do anything. My array should be passed back to main() - how do I get it to save so that I can actually use the output of my function after the program has terminated?

Thanks in advance for your help.

edit - I'm aware that the scope of main() is different, but if I get rid of it I am told that "function definitions are not permitted in this context." It looks like for some reason I can't have a script and some functions which the script uses in the same file.

Comment: The Worskpace has a different scope than the `main` function. That's why you don't see any variables. Remove `function main()`.

Comment: If I do that, the program will not execute, since apparently you can't have a script followed by function definitions in a matlab file. So I guess what I'm really asking is how to get variables from a function workspace into a form that is persistent.

Comment: You pass them back as return values from the function.

Comment: @Nate What you say is correct. If you remove the function header you must save the script and the `analysis` function in separate files. If want to keep the `main` function, you can add an output parameter like this: `function[resultarray] = main()` (see the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html)).

Comment: As a side note, including functions in scripts is allowed in MATLAB R2016b or later.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep `main` as a function with this syntax, then you should edit your code as follows (return `resultarray` from `main`):

```
function resultarray = main()
    object = matfile('data.mat')
    vars = (fieldnames(object))
    resultarray = zeros(length(vars))
    for index = 1:length(vars)
        var = vars(index)
        x = object.var
        resultarray = analysis(x, index)
    end
end

function resultarray = analysis(x, index)
    %does stuff to x
    resultarray(index) = x
    disp(resultarray(index))
end
```

The problem is that the workspace has different scope than the function you have defined.

Otherwise you can create a script called, let's say `main.m`:

```
object = matfile('data.mat')
vars = (fieldnames(object))
resultarray = zeros(length(vars))
for index = 1:length(vars)
    var = vars(index)
    x = object.var
    resultarray = analysis(x, index)
end
```

and create a separate file called `analysis.m`, which will contain the following code:

```
function resultarray = analysis(x, index)
    %does stuff to x
    resultarray(index) = x
end
```